# What is the difference in transmission time and CAN Frame length at physical layer for the following example?

Tags: can-bus

[image]

Can anyone explain me how this exercise within the attached image needs to be solved?

Comment: Just write down, how the messages will look like at the physical layer. You will notice a difference in length and thus transmission time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hint: it's an exercise in understanding bit stuffing in CAN. However, bit stuffing does not happen on the physical layer but at the data link layer, so the question is poorly phrased. LSB vs MSB is irrelevant information.